# Gmail API using C# to update signature

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm trying to use perform a C# Http request to update the signature for my Gmail account, I'm trying to recreate the Http call as shown in this Gmail Test page https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/update, but for some reason the "responseString" variable returns as "Not Found"

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

var userId = "my_email@gmail.com";
var sendAsEmail = "my_email@gmail.com";
var OAuthKey = "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var js = new JsonSerializer();
var payload = new {signature = "Regards<br/>Joe Bloggs"};
var json = js.Serialize(payload);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "message/rfc822");

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/"+userId+"/settings/sendAs/"+sendAsEmail+"?alt=json&key=" + OAuthKey, content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend generating the payload JSON like that. Instead, use a JSON serialiser (e.g. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert from a class / anonymous type to the necessary JSON.

Comment: Ok, I've updated code to include Json Serializer but it makes no difference to "responseString"

Comment: Can you make an update to your question so we can see both your old code and your current code?

Comment: I'm assuming that's not your **actual** email address and oauth key? Because if it is, you probably want to retract that key immediately now that you've spread it on the internet for everyone to see.

Comment: The are .net API clients for all google APIs on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) and on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/google-apis-packages) - use the one for Gmail

Comment: Rather than just concatenating userId and sendAsEmail into the string to post, be sure to URL Encode them first - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx .